# React: setTimeout not clearing within useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently my app switches to the `/about` page after 5s of an intro on the `/home` page.
I want to break this timeout if someone manually changes the page.

For this I have a state of `introDisplayed` which is `false` by default. By clicking on a link within the app the `introDisplayed` is becoming `true`

Why is the setTimeout within the useEffect not clearing?
For reference I have listed all of my attempts on this matter.

clarification:
I've tried adding `introDisplayed` alone to dependencies within useEffect, as well as with `history` and `setIntroDisplayed` as suggested by eslint and it doesn't change anything in this case

```
const Page = ({ introDisplayed, setIntroDisplayed }) => {

  const history = useHistory()

  const location = useLocation()

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (introDisplayed === false) {
  //     setTimeout(() => {
  //       setIntroDisplayed(true)
  //       history.push("/about")
  //     }, 5000)
  //   } else clearTimeout()
  // })
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (introDisplayed === false) {
  //     var timer = setTimeout(() => {
  //       setIntroDisplayed(true)
  //       history.push("/about")
  //     }, 5000)
  //   } else clearTimeout(timer)
  // })
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setIntroDisplayed(true)
      history.push("/about")
    }, 1000)
    if (introDisplayed === true) {
      return () => clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  })

  return ()
}
```

Comment: Your `useEffect` should include `introDisplayed` as a dependency

Comment: I've tried adding `introDisplayed` alone as well as with `history` and `setIntroDisplayed` as suggested by eslint and it doesn't change anything in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've just forgotten to add dependency at `useEffect()`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(introDisplayed === true) return;
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setIntroDisplayed(true)
    history.push("/about")
  }, 1000)
  return () => clearTimeout(timer)
}, [introDisplayed])
```

Comment: Thanks, but as written above:
I've tried adding `introDisplayed` alone as well as with `history` and `setIntroDisplayed` as suggested by eslint and it doesn't change anything in this case

Comment: My bad, your code actually works, sorry! I didn't notice anything different from mine at first, other than the dependency! Thanks a lot